# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2 \omega_k=0 .$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis

I am reading a paper in which there is a part that I don't understand.

> Set $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{z^n}{n ! n !} \text { and } \frac{1}{f(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \omega_n \frac{z^n}{n ! n !} \text {. }$
> Then we have $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2 \omega_k=0$

I tried to choose $z=1$, and then I multiplied both sides of two equations, but I don't know how to transform an infinite sum into a finite sum.

My attempt by using Cauchy product:

$$1=\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^i \frac{z^i}{i ! i !}\right)\left(\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \omega_j \frac{z^i}{j ! j !}\right)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} c_n z^n$$
where

$$c_n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k \frac{1}{k ! k !} \omega_{n-k} \frac{1}{(n-k) !(n-k) !}=\frac{1}{(n !)^2} \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2 \omega_{n-k}$$

Comment: @Sahaj yeah. I am sorry it should be (-1)^n

Comment: Hint: perform the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of the two power series and note that the resulting series must be identically $1$.

Comment: @Gary thank you for your hint. I will try

Comment: @Gary Hello, I tried to use your hint (I updated my post) but I still have difficulties. Could you please help me check it?

Comment: You can change the summation index in the final sum $k\to n-k$ and use ${n\choose n-k} = {n \choose k}$ to get the result you want.

Comment: I added the missing $z$ powers. Follow Winther's hint and then note that the coefficients of $z,z^2,z^3,\ldots$ must all be zero since on the left-hand side we have $1+0\cdot z+0\cdot z^2+\ldots$.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you ^^